# How to restrict Azure App Service as Public Facing site?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

What is the configuration to be performed to restrict Azure App Service as a Public-Facing site?

Comment: Who do you want to visit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `App Service Authentication`, `IP Restrict`, and `VNET` and so on.

**1. App Service Authentication**

[Tutorial: Add authentication to your web app running on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service)

**2. IP Restrict**

[image]

**3. VNET**

[image]